# OpenCV: BFmatcher crashes because of different descriptor shapes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, match, sift

I'm using binary images of the same size, extracting ORB Features but when it comes to compare the descriptors I receive an:

**The Error**

> OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:3757:
>   error: (-215) type == src2.type() &&
>   src1.cols == src2.cols && (type ==
>   CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function
>   batchDistance

However when I check the descriptors with

```
print img.dtype, np.shape(img), np.shape(descriptors)
print oldimg.dtype, np.shape(oldimg), np.shape(olddescriptors)
```

I get

```
uint8 (21, 27) (22, 32)
uint8 (21, 27) (17, 32)
```

Apparently this seems to be the error. On the other hand there's not much I can do against it. Has anybody an idea? At least is there some kind of tutorial online, of how to manually match the descriptors ?

Btw it is the same if I use SIFT, SURF, etc.

**Here's my code:**

I'm working with python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4

```
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=3)
    oldkeypoints, olddescriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(oldimg,None)
    keypoints, descriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(img,None) 

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
    bf.clear()
    bf.add(olddescriptors)
    bf.train()

    matches = bf.match(descriptors) # crashes here
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
```

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39946169/1874627